# PHP SoapClient target namespace not in request params

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am using PHP SoapClient in WSDL mode.

This is what the expected SOAP request should look like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ns="http://xml.m4u.com.au/2009"> 
<soapenv:Header/> 
<soapenv:Body> 
 <ns:sendMessages> 
   <ns:authentication> 
     <ns:userId>Username</ns:userId> 
     <ns:password>Password</ns:password> 
   </ns:authentication> 
   <ns:requestBody> 
     <ns:messages> 
       <ns:message> 
         <ns:recipients> 
           <ns:recipient>61400000001</ns:recipient>  
         </ns:recipients> 
         <ns:content>Message Content</ns:content> 
       </ns:message> 
     </ns:messages> 
   </ns:requestBody> 
 </ns:sendMessages> 
</soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And this is what PHP SoapClient is sending:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns1="http://xml.m4u.com.au/2009">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:sendMessages>
  <ns1:authentication>
    <userId>Username</userId>
    <password>Password</password>
  </ns1:authentication>
  <ns1:requestBody>
    <messages>
      <message>
        <recipients>
          <recipient>61400000001</recipient>
        </recipients>
        <content>Message Content</content>
      </message>
    </messages>
  </ns1:requestBody>
</ns1:sendMessages>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This is how I constructed the client and params:

```
function sendMessages($recipient, $content) {

    $authenticationType = new SoapVar(array('userId' => $this->username, 'password' => $this->password), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);

    $recipientsType = new SoapVar(array('recipient' => $recipient), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
    $messageType = new SoapVar(array('recipients' => $recipientsType, 'content' => $content), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
    $messagesType = new SoapVar(array('message' => $messageType), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);

    $requestBodyType = new SoapVar(array('messages' => $messagesType), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);

    $params = array(
                'authentication' => $authenticationType,
                'requestBody' => $requestBodyType
            );

    try {
        $this->soapClient = new SoapClient($this->wsdl, array('trace' => 1));
        $this->soapClient->__setSoapHeaders(array());

        return $this->soapClient->sendMessages($params);

    } catch (SoapFault $fault) {
        echo '<h2>Request</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($this->soapClient->__getLastRequest(), ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
        trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
    }

}
```

Why is 'ns1' present for 'authentication' and 'requestBody' but missing for their child nodes?
What am I doing wrong? The WSDL is located here => http://soap.m4u.com.au/?wsdl

Appreciate anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the URI of the namespace to encode the object. This will include everything necessary (including your missing namespace). The acronym of the namespace name is irrelevant.

This:

```
$authenticationType = new SoapVar(array('userId' => $this->username, 'password' => $this->password), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
```

should be:

```
$authenticationType = new SoapVar(array('userId' => $this->username, 'password' => $this->password), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, "authentication","http://xml.m4u.com.au/2009");
```

The problem you're seeing with the namespace serialization comes from using `soapvar` without all the parameters. When it serializes the request prior to sending it assumes the namespace is *already* included. If, instead, you had created each as a simple array and included them in `$params` it would include the namespace for the internal parameters correctly. By way of demonstration:

```
$authenticationType = array('userId' => $this->username, 'password' => $this->password)
```

Answer (score 0):

try using nusoap library. Below is sample code:

```
<?php
$wsdl = "http://soap.m4u.com.au/?wsdl";
// generate request veriables
$data = array();

$action = ""; // ws action
$param = ""; //parameters

$options = array(
            'location'  => 'http://soap.m4u.com.au',
            'uri'       => ''
            );
// eof generate request veriables

//$client = new soap_client($wsdl, $options);// create soap client
$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl, 'wsdl');

$client->setCredentials($api_username, $api_password);// set crendencials
$opt = $client->call($action, $param, '', '', false, true);

print_r($opt);
?>
```